# Expanding two gang box to three gang with metal conduit

Tags: electrical, conduit

I live in Chicago so everything in my walls is in metal conduit. In what is currently a two gang box, all three of the top punch out holes are connected to metal conduit. I'd like to expand this to a three gang box, but then the top punch outs will no longer line up with the metal conduits that feed it.

Is there a simple way I can alter the positions of the conduits so they would line up with a three gang box?

[image]

Comment: Can you get a better box?  Not all boxes are configured like that.

Comment: Rather than trying to force the pipes out of place through a small hole in the wall, I would see how they actually line up and then use a 3 gang 2 1/2" or 3 1/2" deep masonry box, a 3 gang extension ring, cisbex rings and/or drill or knockout my own holes to get the depth I need for the existing pipe.  At first glance it looks like the original install used a 1/2" mud ring on a 4x4 deep box but it's hard to tell depth from the picture.  If you connect the box to the current pipe with the existing knockouts how far out of flush is it?

Comment: If you need the pipes to spread apart a bit to hit the knockouts, that's no big deal, but depending on how close to the box they're strapped and whether they're strapped twice, pulling them outward or inward can be quite difficult.  You should only do it if you really have to.

Answer (score 1):

The conduits will bend even if rigid, if thin wall or emt they are easily bent into place.

I pull my wiring out and mark with a paint pen or sharpie stripes take a picture or draw a schematic black wire 1 has 1 stripe white wire 1 has 1. Red 1 has 1 then black 2 has 2 etc.  normally not more than 5 in a box keeps from having so many stripes).

Power off of corse. Disconnect switches, pull nuts, remove fasteners(screws or nails) fit wires and conduit into new box install locknuts /bushings if needed. Anchor usually with screws install switches.

A small pry bar or wonder bar can be a lifesaver muscling the conduit.

try to not skin the wires if you do skin them the world is not over some shrink tubing will fix a skinned bit of insulation.

I have done jobs with rigid a foot up in the wall it was anchored but I could get the conduit into the box with a bit of brute force.

Comment: Trying to do that with the power on would be spectacular lol.

Comment: C'mon guys. No upvotes for this?